# Access Vue.js component property inside Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax, vue.js

The following code refers to a component function which fetches data from an url and tries to set that data to a property. It's not working, seems like `this` is not accessible form the ajax clousure scope.

```
var MyComp = Vue.extend({
props: {
        html_prop: {}
        ....
},
methods: {
        fetchCondiciones: function(url){

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    data: vardata ,
                    success: function(data,status,error) {
                        if( data!=''){
                            this.html_prop = data;
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(data,status,error){
                        alert(error);
                    }
            });

        }

        ...
    }
})
```

How could I make `this` accessible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to `.bind` the `this` context, as the callback is not naturally called in the context of the component:

```
var MyComp = Vue.extend({
props: {
        html_prop: null,
},
        // ....
        fetchCondiciones: function(url){

            $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    cache: false,
                    data: vardata,
                    success: function(data,status,error) {
                        if(data != ''){
                            this.html_prop = data;
                        }
                    }.bind(this), // bind this here
                    error: function(data,status,error){
                        alert(error);
                    }.bind(this) // bind this here
            });

        }

        // ...
});
```

You can learn more about `.bind` and this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 14):

As already answered, `.bind` will fix the issue on this, however, I like to use a different approach, and store `this` in a variable before any Ajax calls or nested functions. Very helpful when your code grows inside the method. It is also easier to read.

You can save `this` to a var called `self` for example. Then use `self` anywhere inside that method without a problem.

```
var MyComp = Vue.extend({
props: {
    html_prop: null,
},
    // ....
    fetchCondiciones: function(url){

        var self = this;

        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                data: vardata,
                success: function(data,status,error) {
                    if(data != ''){
                        self.html_prop = data;
                    }
                }
                error: function(data,status,error){
                    alert(error);
                }
        });

    }

    // ...
});
```

UPDATE:

Today we could just use ES6 arrow function syntax.

The value of `this` inside the function is determined by the surrounding scope, and there is no need to create a new variable, or to use `bind`:

```
    // ....
    fetchCondiciones: url => {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                data: vardata,
                success: (data,status,error) => {
                    if(data != ''){
                        this.html_prop = data;
                    }
                }
                error: (data,status,error) => {
                    alert(error);
                }
        });
    }
```

Or:

```
    // ....
    fetchCondiciones(url) {
        $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                cache: false,
                data: vardata,
                success(data,status,error) {
                    if(data != ''){
                        this.html_prop = data;
                    }
                }
                error(data,status,error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
        });
    }
```

Comment: It's working for me, thanks a lot.  Is it considered good practice or it's a good hack/trick ?

Comment: Works for me too, but I am also wondering which approach is the best ?

Comment: Using the arrow function in the es6 example above is definitely the best approach!

Comment: I also used the 'self' hack for a few years. This is like using a global variable. From my experience, this approach is okay for simple situations, however, one there are multiple parent and child components, and ajax is used in all those components, 'self' may lead to mixup.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide a `context` option and set it to `this` like so:

```
$.ajax({
  context: this, 
  ..
})
```

Which I prefer over binding `this` as it seems more readable, too.

From the [jQuery AJAX docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> The `this` reference within all callbacks is the object in the `context` option passed to `$.ajax` in the settings; if `context` is not specified, `this` is a reference to the Ajax settings themselves.

Comment: its also supported in older jquery versions which is another plus

Answer (score 0):

You can also use arrow functions since ES6, arrow functions do not bind their own `this`, instead, they inherit the one from the parent scope, which is called "lexical scoping".
so instead of

```
//....                
  success: function(data,status,error) {
                        if( data!=''){
                            this.html_prop = data;
           }
  }
//...
```

you can do

```
//....                
  success: (data,status,error) => {
                        if( data!=''){
                            this.html_prop = data;
            }
  }
//...
```